# why does the output contains new line despite using end=""

Tags: python, file, while-loop

Why does the output contain newline despite using `end=""`

```
with open("mydata.txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write("myname is \nTimduudy\nIm from eggyork\nrefff")


with open("mydata.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as myfile:
    line_num = 1
    while True:
        line = myfile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print("Line", line_num, ":", line, end="")
        line_num += 1
```

output:

```
Line 1 : myname is 
Line 2 : Timduudy
Line 3 : Im from eggyork
Line 4 : refff
```

Comment: Because you have used newline char in your string `\n`

Comment: `myfile.readline()` includes the newline that terminate the line at the end of the string (except possibly for the last line).  `end=""` does nothing to eliminate an actual newline character in the items being printed, it just means to not add another one.

Comment: the `end` parameter only changes what `print` adds to the end of the printed string. If the string actually contains a newline character itself, that will still be printed.

Comment: I see, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that `readline()` methods keeps the newline character '\n' at the end of each line. To strip it, you can do:

```
line = myfile.readline().strip('\n')
```

You can also use `strip()` with no parameter but it will also remove trailing white spaces.

Comment: @bitbitbitter You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer (by clicking on Accept) if it is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `line = myfile.readline().strip()` this will remove the newline from every line.

Comment: .strip("\n")..But yeah Thanks!